# SQL min / max with all fields

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I am facing a simple problem with an SQL query that I do not know how to tackle.

I have a table with the following structure

```
CITY COUNTRY DATES TEMPERATURE
```

Note that for a given country, I can have several cities. And, for a given city, I have several rows giving me the TEMPERATURE at each available DATE. This is just a time serie.

I would like to write a query which gives me for every cities the DATE where the TEMPERATURE is the MIN and the DATE where the TEMPERATURE is the MAX. The query should return something like that:

```
CITY COUNTRY DATE_MIN_TEMPERATURE MIN_TEMPERATURE DATE_MAX_TEMPERATURE MAX_TEMPERATURE
```

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Best regards,

Deny

Comment: What do you want shown if for a given city there are two different days when the minimum temperature was achieved?

Comment: Good point. I can deal with any of the date ...

Answer (score 1):

Oracle provides `keep`/`dense_rank first` for this purpose:

```
select city,
       min(temperature) as min_temperature,
       max(date) keep (dense_rank first order by temperature asc) as min_temperature_date,
       max(temperature) as max_temperature,
       max(date) keep (dense_rank first order by temperature desc) as max_temperature_date
from t
group by city;
```

Note that this returns only one date if there are ties.  If you want to handle that, more logic is needed:

```
select city, min(temperature) as min_temperature,
       listagg(case when seqnum_min = 1 then date end, ',') within group (order by date) as mindates,
       max(temperature) as max_temperature,
       listagg(case when seqnum_max = 1 then date end, ',') within group (order by date) as maxdates,
from (select t.*,
             rank() over (partition by city order by temperature) as seqnum_min,
             rank() over (partition by city order by temperature desc) as seqnum_max
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum_min = 1 or seqnum_max = 1
group by city;
```

Comment: Too bad the `first` and `last` functions don't work with `listagg` as the aggregate function! (Really not clear why they don't, but they don't.) It would be cool to be able to combine both ideas in one.

Comment: err... the second solution has several missing keywords, typos, "date" doesn't work as a column name, etc. After fixing all of those, the solution gives the wrong answer. (Probably because the second row_number() call should order by temperature **desc**?) And it shouldn't be `row_number()`, it should be `rank()` anyway. Way too many errors.

Comment: @mathguy . . . `date` is the column provided by the OP.  I see no reason to escape it, because that probably isn't the actual name of the column.  I think other typos are fixed.  The comment on `rank()` is very much to the point, but really, it is the first query that actually answers the OP's question.

Comment: @mathguy I fixed the usage of the reserved DATE keyword

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 11 and above, you can use PIVOT. In the solution below I use LISTAGG to show all the dates in case of ties. Another option is, in the case of ties, to show the most recent date when the extreme temperature was reached; if that is preferred, simply replace `LISTAGG(dt, ....)` (including the `WITHIN GROUP` clause) with `MAX(dt)`. However, in that case the first solution offered by Gordon (using the `first` function) is more efficient anyway - no need for pivoting.

Note that I changed "date" to "dt" - DATE is a reserved word in Oracle. I also show the rows by country first, then city (the more logical ordering). I created test data in a WITH clause, but the solution is everything below the comment line.

```
with
     inputs ( city, country, dt, temperature ) as (
       select 'Palermo', 'Italy'  , date '2014-02-13',  3 from dual union all
       select 'Palermo', 'Italy'  , date '2002-01-23',  3 from dual union all
       select 'Palermo', 'Italy'  , date '1998-07-22', 42 from dual union all
       select 'Palermo', 'Italy'  , date '1993-08-24', 30 from dual union all
       select 'Maseru' , 'Lesotho', date '1994-01-11', 34 from dual union all
       select 'Maseru' , 'Lesotho', date '2004-08-13', 12 from dual
     )
--  >>  end test data; solution (SQL query) begins with the next line
select country, city,
       "'min'_DT" as date_min_temp, "'min'_TEMP" as min_temp,
       "'max'_DT" as date_max_temp, "'max'_TEMP" as max_temp
from ( 
       select city, country, dt, temperature,
              case when temperature = min(temperature) 
                        over (partition by city, country) then 'min'
                   when temperature = max(temperature) 
                        over (partition by city, country) then 'max' 
                   end as flag
       from inputs
     )
pivot ( listagg(to_char(dt, 'dd-MON-yyyy'), ', ') 
        within group (order by dt) as dt, min(temperature) as temp
        for flag in ('min', 'max'))
order by country, city    --  ORDER BY is optional
;

COUNTRY CITY    DATE_MIN_TEMP              MIN_TEMP DATE_MAX_TEMP    MAX_TEMP
------- ------- ------------------------ ---------- -------------- ----------
Italy   Palermo 23-JAN-2002, 13-FEB-2014          3 22-JUL-1998            42
Lesotho Maseru  13-AUG-2004                      12 11-JAN-1994            34

2 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `keep/dense_rank first` function you can also use `FIRST_VALUE` and `LAST_VALUE`:

```
select distinct city,
   MIN(temperature) OVER (PARTITION BY city) as min_temperature,
   FIRST_VALUE(date) OVER (PARTITION BY city ORDER BY temperature) AS min_temperature_date,
   MAX(temperature) OVER (PARTITION BY city) as max_temperature,
   LAST_VALUE(date) OVER (PARTITION BY city ORDER BY temperature) AS max_temperature_date
FROM t;
```